# How "this" in methods of Javascript Number objects be converted to the numeric value of the object?

Tags: javascript

It seems in Number objects, numeric values can be referenced directly using "this" instead of  this.valueOf() or something like "this.value", for example:

```
Number.prototype.printPlusOne=function(){ 
      var tmp=this+1;
      alert(tmp); 
}
var n=new Number("5");
n.printPlusOne();
```

And why is this possible(using "this" directly instead of "this.valueOf()" in the addition above)?
I didn't find this feature in the Number specification, Did I missed something?
And further more, Is this automatic conversion feature used in other classes of objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither operand of the `+` operator is a string, so JavaScript calls `valueOf` to implicitly convert the Object (a `Number`, in this case) to a primitive value, in order to perform numeric addition. Quoting David Flanagan:

> If the object has a `valueOf()` method that returns a primitive value, JavaScript converts (if necessary) that primitive value to a number and returns the result.

So, `this` is implicitly converted to its primitive value.

If you did something silly like override `Number.valueOf`:

```
Number.prototype.valueOf = function() {
    return 10;
}
```

then your function would alert *11* instead.

Comment: Thanks, and I just learned When one operand of the `+` is a string, then the object's toString() is called implicitly to convert it to a string.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're trying to accomplish here, but:

```
Number.prototype.print=function(){ 
      alert(this.valueOf()); 
}

var n=new Number("5");
n.print();
```

Comment: I edited the question again, I just wonder why "this" can be used instead of "this.valueOf()"